# Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory (Deploy, npm)

Tags: asp.net, vue.js, npm, deployment

When to deploy in npm i have err code 134 and

> FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation
> failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

I have `NODE_OPTIONS --max_old_space_size=2048` and change on `setx NODE_OPTIONS --max_old_space_size=4096. But I didn’t solve the problem. During the previous deployment everything was fine.

Answer (score 0):

I freed up more RAM and the deployment was successful. I hope this information will be useful to someone.